# Get most viewed url by users in a day

Tags: mysql, unix

I have a table whose structure like this

```
id time       userid ip              course module cmid action url                     info
 1 1441006367      2 110.142.152.217      1 user      0 update view.php?id=2&course=1 
 2 1441006397      2 110.142.152.217      1 course    0 view   view.php?id=1              1
 3 1441061491      2 110.142.152.217      1 user      0 view   view.php?id=0&course=1     2
 4 1441061491      2 110.142.152.217      1 course    0 view   view.php?id=1              1
 5 1441067607      2 110.142.152.217      1 course    0 view   view.php?id=1              1
 6 1441067617      2 110.142.152.217      1 course    0 view   view.php?id=1              1
 7 1441067646      2 110.142.152.217      1 course    0 view   view.php?id=1              1
 8 1441067681      2 110.142.152.217      1 course    0 view   view.php?id=1              1
 9 1441067774      2 110.142.152.217      1 course    0 view   view.php?id=1              1
10 1441069218      2 110.142.152.217      1 course    0 view   view.php?id=1              1
11 1441071815      2 110.142.152.217      1 course    0 view   view.php?id=1              1
12 1441071815      2 110.142.152.217      1 course    0 login  view.php?id=1              1
13 1441080275      2 110.142.152.217      1 user      0 view   view.php?id=0&course=1     2
14 1441080275      2 110.142.152.217      1 course    0 view   view.php?id=1              1
15 1441080275      2 110.142.152.217      1 course    0 view   view.php?id=1              1
16 1441082380      2 110.142.152.217      1 course    0 view   view.php?id=1              1
17 1441082494      2 110.142.152.217      1 course    0 view   view.php?id=1              1
18 1441082498      2 110.142.152.217      1 user      0 logout view.php?id=2&course=1     2
19 1441082504      2 110.142.152.217      1 user      0 login  view.php?id=0&course=1     2
20 1441082505      2 110.142.152.217      1 user      0 login  view.php?id=0&course=1     2
21 1441082508      2 110.142.152.217      1 user      0 login  view.php?id=0&course=2     2
22 1441082508      2 110.142.152.217      1 user      0 loam   view.DhD?id=0&course=1     2
```

I want to get most viewed url by users in a day where each url belongs to different course. One user can view multiple url but not same course.
I tried this query

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT `course`),`userid`,`course`,`module`,`url`, FROM_UNIXTIME(`time`,'%Y-%m-%d') as date FROM `mdl_log` where `time`>unix_timestamp('2016-06-01 00:00:00') AND `time`<unix_timestamp('2016-06-02 00:00:00') GROUP BY `course`
```

When i run this it restrict same course by a user which is right but this restrict also for other user.
For example if one user viewed same course 2 time then it count one(that's right) but it not count for user who viewed 1 time.Means they not getting same course for other user. Please help me what i am doing wrong..

Comment: It's a little odd to group by the thing you're counting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are counting the column you are grouping by ! that is totally wrong.

You should count `DISTINCT USER_ID` :

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT `userid`),`userid`,`course`,`module`,`url`, FROM_UNIXTIME(`time`,'%Y-%m-%d') as date 
FROM `mdl_log` 
where `time`>unix_timestamp('2016-06-01 00:00:00') AND 
      `time`<unix_timestamp('2016-06-02 00:00:00')
GROUP BY `course`
```

I don't understand why are you even selecting `userid` ? It will be randomly picked because it's not a part of the group by clause.